# Building GCC 4.8.2 in OS X 10.9

Tags: gcc, osx-mavericks

I'm trying to compile and install GCC 4.8.2 in OS X 10.9. I followed the instructions  here (http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/InstallingGCC) to first run `./contrib/download_prerequesites` and then ran configure and make from a directory different from the source. My build fails with error:

```
checking for suffix of object files... configure: error: in `/Users/prokilogrammer/temp/gcc-build482/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/libgcc':
configure: error: cannot compute suffix of object files: cannot compile
See `config.log' for more details.
```

Apparently this problem would be solved if GCC's dependencies (GMP, MPC, MPFR) are properly installed (http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/FAQ#configure_suffix). I checked and made sure they are correctly installed under /usr/local/lib & /usr/local/include directories.

Looking at config.log, I see the following errors:

```
configure:3565: checking for suffix of object files
configure:3587: /Users/prokilogrammer/temp/gcc-build482/./gcc/xgcc -B/Users/prokilogrammer/temp/gcc-build482/./gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2/sys-include    -c -g -O2  conftest.c >&5
conftest.c:1:0: internal compiler error: Segmentation fault: 11
 /* confdefs.h */
 ^
libbacktrace could not find executable to open
```

I am not sure if the segfault is because of the missing dependencies or a legit issue in gcc.

Have you guys experienced similar problems? Is there a solution/workaround?

PS: I have also tried setting LD_LIBRARY_PATH & DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH without any luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've built GCC 4.8.2 on several Mavericks machines, but I chose a slightly different strategy.  Specifically, I included the code for GMP, MPC, MPFR (and CLOOG and ISL) in the build directory.  I used a script to quasi-automate it:

```
GCC_VER=gcc-4.8.2
tar -xf ${GCC_VER}.tar.bz2 || exit 1

cd ${GCC_VER} || exit

cat <<EOF |
    cloog 0.18.0 tar.gz 
    gmp 5.1.3 tar.xz 
    isl 0.11.1 tar.bz2 
    mpc 1.0.1 tar.gz 
    mpfr 3.1.2 tar.xz
EOF

while read file vrsn extn
do
    tar -xf "../$file-$vrsn.$extn" &&
    ln -s "$file-$vrsn" "$file"
done
```

With that done:

```
mkdir gcc-4.8.2-obj
cd gcc-4.8.2-obj
../gcc-4.8.2/configure --prefix=$HOME/gcc/v4.8.2
make -j8 bootstrap
```

AFAICR, that was about all it took, with 4.8.1 and 4.8.2.

Comment: Thanks for the instructions. I followed your instructions, but without any success. I am getting the same error. I am not sure what is wrong with my environment that is screwing things.

Comment: Sorry to hear that. Which compiler do you have pre-installed? I was using XCode 5.  Are you able to get that compiler to compile any code? I don't have any `/usr/local/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2` directory. Does that mean you're using a GCC compiled previously?

Comment: Ooops; I did the builds earlier in October, and I'm seeing darwin12.x instead of 13.x, which indicates a Mountain Lion rather than Mavericks build.  So, I've moved my GCC 4.8.2 out of the way, and redone the configuration, etc, using the XCode gcc for the bootstrap phase. I'm using the script outlined above, combining the two fragments.  So far, so good...I'm tracing it all.

Comment: It took about 45 minutes on a machine with 16 GiB RAM and SSD drive, but the compilation was completed successfully on my machine, using the Apple-provided '`gcc`' (where `/usr/bin/gcc -version` says: `Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix`) to bootstrap the build.

Comment: Actually yes. I just realized that I installed osx-gcc-installer which bootstrapped the gcc build. I didn't realize this package was not officially supported in 10.9. I uninstalled this package and installed XCode. Now I'm able to compile gcc fine :) Thanks for the help.
PS: Btw, I used Home Brew to compile gcc this time.